# Image URL to Base64 encoded data

Tags: java

I am trying to convert an image(Web URL) to Base64 encoded string using Java. The below code works fine for the below URL

https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE1Mu3b

However, fails for most other image URLs

e.g. https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png

Seems like it fails in the openStream() step in the code.

```
try{
    URI attURI = new URI(strURL);
    importanttrace.addWarning(attURI.toASCIIString());
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(attURI.toASCIIString());
    InputStream is = url.openStream(); //erroring
    byte[] bytes = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    String res = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    return res;
}
catch (Exception e) {
return "err";
}
```

Can someone help me understand what the issue may be? Thanks for your help!

EDIT: It is a FIREWALL issue.

Comment: Fails how?  Provide the full error message(s) and stack trace(s) for your failures.

Comment: And dragging in Apache Commons to convert an input stream to a `byte` array?  Just copy the InputStream to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.  You can even wrap that `ByteArrayOutputStream` with a base64 encoding stream and save a copy step.

Comment: Seems like the corporate firewall maybe blocking the request except for the Microsoft link which seems to be reachable. Error is: 

org.w3c.www.protocol.http.HttpException: Connection closed by remote host.